# Can we add UIbuttons, uilabels on to webview and make them scrollable along with the web view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I was working on webview. I am facing an issue where I want to display html as well as UIbuttons.

I made webview added Ui butons but when I scroll webview the webview scrolls but the uibuttons remain at the same location.

Answer (score 2):

I've not actually tried this, but in theory this should be possible on iOS 5. If you just add the button to the `UIWebView` it won't work - as you'll find, when you scroll the views you add remain in place. In iOS 5 Apple added the `scrollView` property to `UIWebView`, so if you add your views to that instead (the scroll view) you may find it works?

Comment: But the problem is that i cant upgrade to ios 5 its really an urgent requirement currently